# How to do online retraining of model on a single new data point/observation?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-modeling, training, optimization

I am trying to investigate the effect on performance on old data and new data when a classifier is retrained on only the new observation when it is encountered. The aim is to retrain the classifier on this single observation and make it classify it correctly whilst maintaining its performance on the old data.

However, retraining seems to cause catastrophic forgetting without learning the new observation.

I have tried decreasing the learning rate but that only decreased the forgetting but the new observation is still not learnt.

Has anyone attempted to do this before, gone through this experience or know of any examples online that I can learn from, please?

Thanks

Comment: You can do it for Gradient Descent based model _e.g. LR, Neural net_. Few other models too support it. How are you doing it and which Framework are you using.

Comment: I am trying to implement this approach for the MNIST dataset using a CNN and an SGD optimiser.

Comment: Here is the CNN structure:
`
#CNN sturcture
class Net(nn.Module):
 def __init__(self):
  super(Net, self).__init__()
  self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 10, kernel_size=5)
  self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 20, kernel_size=5)
  self.conv2_drop = nn.Dropout2d()
  self.fc1 = nn.Linear(320, 50)
  self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, 10)

 def forward(self, x):
  x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv1(x), 2))
  x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2_drop(self.conv2(x)), 2))
  x = x.view(-1, 320)
  x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
  x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
  x = self.fc2(x)
  return x`

Comment: @10xAI do you have any examples available online or posts that you know of that implement what I am looking at for a Gradient Descent based model  so I can compare it to my work please? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There is nothing special in that process. Just the weights must be saved (_There are few others point too but this is the most important_). I wanted to know the steps you are following _esp. how are you saving the weights_ and start the retraining from the same weight values?